# I want to extracting css image path by Java Pattern expression

Tags: java, regex

All , I want to write a pattern regex to extract the: `"/images/colorbox/ie6/borderBottomRight.png"` from `cssContent=".cboxIE6 #cboxBottomRight{background:url(../images/colorbox/ie6/borderBottomRight.png);}"`

Who can write a pattern regex for me? Thanks a lot.

My regex can't work as:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[.*]*/:url/(/././/(.+?)/)/;[.*]*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(cssContent);
if(matcher.find()){
   System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":url\\(\\.\\.([^)]+)\\)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(cssContent);
if(matcher.find()){
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

The regex used to match is *(quoted and without `\` escaped)*

```
":url\(\.\.([^)]+)\)"
```

which looks for `:url(..` followed by `[^)]` anything that's not a closing `)` bracket `+` one or more times; finally followed by the closing `)` bracket. The group `()` captured is available at `group(1)` whereas `group(0)` would give you the complete string that matched i.e. from `:url` to the closing `)`.

Comment: Thank you so much , It works well , After I see your short expression , I see a lot , Thank you again .

Answer (score 0):

The biggest error you were making was using "/" to escape your literal characters.  You need to use "\", and annoyingly, in a java string "\" must be escaped with "\", so the total escape sequence is "\\".  Then, you have `matcher.group(0), which matches the entire pattern.  You need`matcher.group(1)` to match the first (and only) group in your regex, which contains your string of interest.  Here's the corrected code:

```
String cssContent = "cssContent=\".cboxIE6 #cboxBottomRight{background:url(../images/colorbox/ie6/borderBottomRight.png);}\"";
String regex = ".*?:url\\(\\.\\.(.+?)\\);[.*]*";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(cssContent);
if(matcher.find()){
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```